# Inner working of OP_IF and OP_ELSE

Tags: script, transaction-verification, opcodes

How does `OP_ELSE` work exactly? Is there an `else if` in Script?

---

According to https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script#Flow_control, the statements after an `OP_ELSE` are executed in three cases. It says:

> If the preceding OP_IF or OP_NOTIF or OP_ELSE was not executed then these statements are.

I'd like to understand how the 3rd case works, i.e. when there's a preceding `OP_ELSE` that is not followed. Consider this script and a `True` at the top of the stack:

```
OP_IF
    <foo>
OP_ELSE
    <bar>
OP_ELSE
    <baz>
OP_ENDIF
```

If we follow the explanation of the quote to the letter, then that means that `<foo>` and `<baz>` are executed. This however is quite counter-intuitive. If this is the case, then the second `OP_ELSE` is redundant, as `<baz>` can simply go after `<foo>` to the same effect and with less opcodes.

Is there some other interpretation I'm missing?

I stumbled upon this detail while trying to write a script with 3 different branches, something like

```
OP_IF top stack item is 0
    <foo>
OP_ELSEIF top stack item is 1
   <bar>
OP_ELSE
   <baz>
OP_ENDIF
```

I know the above isn't valid Script, but can something to this effect be achieved without resorting to the following?

```
OP_IF
    <foo>
OP_ELSE
    OP_IF
        <bar>
    OP_ELSE
        <baz>
    OP_ENDIF
OP_ENDIF
```

Note that this is more expensive not only because it has more opcodes, but because two stack items are needed in the witness in order to execute `<bar>` or `<baz>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Inner working of conditionals in Bitcoin Script

The conditionals in Bitcoin Script are conceptually implemented using a stack of booleans, each boolean indicating whether to execute the current opcode when iterating through the Script for each depth of the conditional (nested IF / ELSE).

To grasp the functioning, let's first consider a single-boolean conditioned execution of opcodes. The interpreter will iterate through the Script by setting the boolean to `true` (do execute ops) at the beginning. When encountering an `IF` it will set the boolean to the value of the pushed data preceding the `IF`, casted to a boolean (`CastToBool` in the reference implementation).
If this was `true` it will continue the execution of the following opcodes, effectively executing "the `if {}` branch".
If it was `false`, it will suspend execution until .... It encounters an `ELSE`! Encountering an `ELSE` will toggle the global boolean suspending execution. If it was previously `false`, it will become `true` and effectively execute "the `else {}` branch".  To the contrary if it was `true`, it will become `false` and suspend execution of "the `else {}` branch".

With a bit of ASCII art (`fExec` is the global boolean telling whether to actually execute the OPs):

```
Value of fExec:  true    true      true         true  true    true         false      false            ???

Script        : |start| OP_BLABLA OP_DOSOMETHING <1> OP_IF OP_DOSOMESTUFF OP_ELSE OP_DOANOTHERSTUFF OP_ENDIF
```

```
Value of fExec:  true    true      true         true  false    false       true      true             ???

Script        : |start| OP_BLABLA OP_DOSOMETHING <0> OP_IF OP_DOSOMESTUFF OP_ELSE OP_DOANOTHERSTUFF OP_ENDIF
```

Note how i marked the value of `fExec` as `???` when encountering `OP_ENDIF`. That's because the real implementation is slightly more complicated: in order to support nested conditionals, this is not a single boolean but a vector of booleans that are used to determine execution. That is:

- `OP_IF` will push a new boolean to the vector
- `OP_ELSE` will toggle the last boolean of the vector
- `OP_ENDIF` will pop the last element of the vector

### Going further

#### Multiple `ELSE` for a single `IF`

Note that the implementation of the `ELSE` being a single toggle it means that nothing prevents to toggle two times in a row. That is, you can have many following `ELSE` opcodes before the `ENDIF`. Two following `ELSE`s would effectively toggle the last boolean twice, hence executing the following opcodes as it would for "the `if {}` branch".

Therefore in the example from your question:

```
OP_IF <foo> OP_ELSE <bar> OP_ELSE <baz> OP_ENDIF
```

That's indeed `<foo>` and `<baz>` that will be executed.

#### Quadratic behaviour when computing `fExec` from the vector of booleans

The implementation of the conditional logic was [modified in 2020 by Pieter Wuille](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/16902) to fix a [quadratic behaviour found by Segio Demian Lerner](https://bitslog.com/2017/04/17/new-quadratic-delays-in-bitcoin-scripts/).
Therefore the actual implementation does not actually use a stack for the booleans anymore, rather it stores the "top boolean" in a dedicated data structure imitating the previous implementation.

#### Slightly related Tapscript rule

The proposed new addition to the Script rules as part of the proposed Taproot soft fork [(Tapscript) lifts the limit of `201` OP codes](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0342.mediawiki#cite_ref-10-0). This was made possible by the elimination of the aforementioned quadratic behaviour.

Comment: IIUC, the behavior of multiple `OP_ELSE` for a single `OP_IF` is indeed the "redundant" one described in the question, correct? And there is no `OP_ELSEIF` equivalent?

Comment: Yes, i edited the answer to precisely answer your example :)